# irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, irreducible-polynomials

Let $\epsilon=\exp({\frac{2i\pi}{9}})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\epsilon)$ be a cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of order 9. If $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\epsilon)$, determine the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$.

Comment: Do you mean the *minimal* polynomial? And, what is $\alpha$ actually?

Comment: The answer will depend on $\alpha$. It could have degree $1,2,3$ or $6$.

Comment: Also, a little "please" and showing some self work and effort won't hurt...